# Web page doesn't render using python requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** the text from this webpage using the requests and BeautifulSoup module in python: https://seekingalpha.com/article/4441901-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q3-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript

However once the request has been made and I try and get the text using the following code, I only get the following text:

```
url = "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4441901-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q3-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript"
head={'YOUR HEADER PARAMETERS'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=head)
transcript = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser').text
```

The text:

```
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q3 2021 Results - Earnings Call Transcript | Seeking Alpha


Javascript is Disabled
Your current browser configurationis not compatible with this site.
```

Is there any way I can get round this to get the text from the webpage?

Thanks

Comment: Use `selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the URL is being loaded by an API. I have tried to get the title and content.

Here is the API endpoint. *You can make a GET request to this end-point and find the data you need.*

> `https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/articles/4441901?include=author%2CprimaryTickers%2CsecondaryTickers%2CotherTags%2Cpresentations%2Cpresentations.slides%2Cauthor.authorResearch%2Cco_authors%2CpromotedService%2Csentiments`

The `content` (*I mean the variable content*) is in HTML format, you can use `beautifulsoup` to extract whatever data you need.

Here is the code that prints the `title` and some `content`.

```
import requests
url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/articles/4441901?include=author%2CprimaryTickers%2CsecondaryTickers%2CotherTags%2Cpresentations%2Cpresentations.slides%2Cauthor.authorResearch%2Cco_authors%2CpromotedService%2Csentiments'

r = requests.get(url)
r = r.json()
title = r['data']['attributes']['title']
content = r['data']['attributes']['content']

print(title)
print(content[:500].strip())
```

```
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q3 2021 Results - Earnings Call Transcript

<p>Apple Inc. <span class="ticker-hover-wrapper">(NASDAQ:<a href="https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL" title="Apple Inc.">AAPL</a>)</span> Q3 2021 Earnings Conference Call July 27, 2021  5:00 PM ET</p>
<p><strong>Company Participants</strong></p>
<p>Tejas Gala - Director of IR and Corporate Finance</p>
<p>Tim Cook - CEO</p>
<p>Luca Maestri - CFO</p>
<p><strong>Conference Call Participants</strong></p>
<p>Chris Caso - Raymond James</p>
<p>Jim Suva - Citigroup</p>
<p>Shannon Cross - Cross Resea
.
.
.
```

Comment: That's great, thanks will test the solution. How is it you were able to find the api url?

Comment: You can see that using Chrome Dev Tools -> Network. It will show you all the requests made by the webpage.